# Format date to iso.8601

Tags: php, wordpress, date, xml-rpc, strtotime

I'm working with the wordpress XMLRPC to post some future posts to my blog, but I'm running into some issues with date formatting... basically got myself all discombobulated :)

So I've set up the "future" post date.  It's just fine.

```
$thetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+ $number days", strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))));
```

($thetime echos out the date i'm shooting for - so all is well here)

But the wp client wants the date in ISO.8601 format. So I changed it this way:

```
$content['date_created'] = date( 'c', strtotime($thetime) );
```

But I'm getting a response from the xml-rpc client that it's malformed.

So how would you go about changing $thetime to iso.8601 format since I thought that's what 'c' does?  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the date is the culprit?

Comment: Yes - I can submit a post with out a date (just blanking that field out) and it works fine.  It's only when I try to pass the date that it's got an issue.

Comment: Specifically:  $content['date_created_gmt'] = date( 'c', strtotime($thetime) );   Could the problem be that i'm not changing it to GMT as well?

Comment: I'm sure this will help someone else based on the number of people i've found having the same issue.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/please-helpgetting-date

Solved my formatting issue - and it's not covered anywhere else I could find.

Answer (score 3):

First, verify the outputted string and make sure that the output is what you expect. There may be a completely unrelated bug (for example a forgotten debugging `echo`) in there.

Some implementations may require the date to be in UTC time. Simply use [`gmdate`](http://php.net/gmdate) instead of `date`, and add a [`Z`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_time) at the end:

```
$content['date_created'] = gmdate('Y-m-d\\TG:i:s\\Z', strtotime($thetime)) . 'Z';
```

Comment: If i don't convert to srtotime the dates are correct - after that they are just numbers so I'm assuming they are correct. This could be a problem with WP as well since I see others having issues doing future posts.  Digging a little deeper there

Comment: @EdCharkow Oops, php already does include a timezone. Rewrote the answer. The final ouput (ISO8601) should be perfectly human-readable, in the format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[+-]hh:mm. For example, the current time is `2011-12-20T20:04:46Z`, or `2011-12-20T21:04:46+01:00` (with CET timezone spec).

Answer (score 0):

According to [XMLRPC specifications](http://xmlrpc.scripting.com/spec.html), datetime is defined in this tag `<dateTime.iso8601>`
 and has this format 19980717T14:08:55. So the complete tag looks like this 
`<dateTime.iso8601>20090322T23:43:03</dateTime.iso8601>`

This is the common mistake when using php `xmlrpc_encode_request()` function, which does not automatically convert date.  Rather use `xmlrpc_set_type()` function.

```
<?php

$params = date("Ymd\TH:i:s", time());
xmlrpc_set_type($params, 'datetime');
echo xmlrpc_encode($params);

?>
```

The above example will output something similar to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<params>
<param>
 <value>
  <dateTime.iso8601>20090322T23:43:03</dateTime.iso8601>
 </value>
</param>
</params>
```